# ZipCode to ZipCode Storage

Tags: database-design, mariadb

I'm working on a project that requires me to allow users to store/edit properties of what they call "path". A path can be any Zip Code to any other Zip Code.

The system they have now, utilizes one table for 3 digit to 3 digit system for default properties, and then if exceptions to the 3to3 are needed, there's another table that does the 5 digit to 5 digit.

```
123 > 345
12345 > 34567
```

Making changes is interesting for them, because it becomes a game to figure out exceptions (5 to 5) in relation to the 3 to 3 properties. Add in the fact that going from zip 12345 to zip 98765 isn't the same as doing the reverse 98765 to 12345.

So, they'd rather have one table that has the immediate detail of "every 5 digit zip code to every 5 digit zip code". By my calculations that means close to 2 billion rows (43000 x 43000. since there's about that many valid zips in the US).

That just seems like a bad idea to me, but without going right back to the situation they already have, I can't see a way around it.

I thought about storing them as one single combination, but then having the extra fields for either direction. Like this:

```
Zip1: 12345
Zip2: 98765
1to2 Property 1: 
2to1 Property 1:
1to2 Property 2:
2to1 Property 2:
1to2 Property 3:
2to1 Property 3:
```

This would reduce the number of rows to under 1 billion. I would just setup the Zip1 to Zip2 as the primary key, and then have a unique index for the reverse Zip2 to Zip1.

Has anyone ever seen a neat trick or idea to storing data like this?

Comment: Simpler yet, use the Google API to compute it _realtime_.

Comment: There's nothing to compute. I'm just storing properties of a zip to zip relationship.

Comment: *"path can be any Zip Code to any other Zip Code"* this doesn't make much sense to me. I would *love* to hear how you're using it. Google 77345 (that's me!). Google 77344. They're not even contiguous (that's 3 hours away).

Comment: @EvanCarroll  The word "path" is just a term. It has no bearing on distances. Let's do Team to Team relationships instead. Maybe I need to store the person who sends emails from T1 to T2. Distance has no impact on that relationship. All we need to know, is that this company has a specific need to specify that a person handles the emails from T1 to T2 and a different person might handle the T2 to A1 emails. That's the situation here, but with zip codes. It's not a geography problem. Imagine 43000 teams that you need to store that level of detail for.

Comment: So wouldn't it better to divvy up those teams based on work load and not arbitrary USPS data? Or to pool your 2 billion data points to 43000 teams equally?

Comment: @EvanCarroll No. It wouldn't.

Comment: Fair enough. I can't imagine a system the used ZIP codes that could not be better engineered to not use ZIP codes, but you're not obligated to agree. =)

Comment: @EvanCarroll it's because you're still trying to solve a geography problem. Which this isn't.

Comment: You have your answer either way with how to store it in an optimized fashion. I'm not actually convinced it is a geographical problem, I'm totally indifferent. Either way, being a geographical problem or not, I find it *equally* unconvincing that ZIP codes are a good solution.

Comment: @SysChaos re: you need to mention Canadian Zip codes in the question now.

Comment: @SysChaos at this point, I'm confused at what would be a desirable answer? You've defined the problem as not geographical so I can't suggest storing WGS84 cords and GIS to solve this problem, and you've withheld business information to suggest alternatives. Essentially, you want to use totally ad-hoc arbitrary postal codes from different nations created over 50 years ago that have no geographical relevance for your task to divide up an unstated workload and you're asking how to best use arbitrary data to do that? You may need a consultant.

Comment: It;s not at all clear what the problem is. Do you want to store arbitrary "ZIP" codes? Simple, use a `varchar(X)` column, where X is big enough to hold your lengthier codes. Do you want to store a many-to-many relationship between such codes? Do what is common, a many-to-many table with a `(zip_start, zip_finish)` `unique` constraint.

Comment: If _users_ are going to create "paths", are you expecting them to enter 2 billion paths?

Comment: @RickJames No, I could prepopulate the database with information we already have on hand. From there on out, it would be management. The information is generally static and doesn't change very often.

Comment: A 2-billion row table is possible with MariaDB.  Efficiency is great for "point queries", even if the data is too big to be cached in RAM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partial answer:  Given that you need to look up ($z1, $z2):

```
WHERE zip1 = LEAST($z1, $z2)
  AND zip2 = GREATEST($z1, $z2)
```

For prep, you have only the `PRIMARY KEY(zip1, zip2)` and you have filled the table only with smaller zip to larger zip.  And adjusted the 1to2, etc, columns accordingly.

Comment: How could I enforce that the table only has the smaller to larger? For example... if 12345 to 98765 exists, can I put a constraint on the table to stop 98765 to 12345 from being written? I thought that's what a Unique Index would provide, but that doesn't work the way I thought.

Comment: @SysChaos - I consider that to be a application problem.  There are only a few "constraints" that a database can easily enforce.

Comment: Got it. That's what I figured. I could do that.

Comment: @SysChaos - Bear in mind that this cuts the table down to 1 billion rows.  But each row is almost twice as wide.  Net effect:  Not much change in disk space or performance.  That is, this suggestion may not be worth doing.

Comment: Understood. I know its not the best situation, but we're really painted into a corner. If I could continue to maintain the 3to3 we'd be much better off, however they claim it makes it MORE difficult to maintain when the level of granularity isn't at the lowest level.

Comment: Well, they're right. Also, it's not a shortcoming of constraints. It's just MySQL (afaik), for instance in PostgreSQL `CREATE TABLE f ( int a, int b, UNIQUE ( greatest(a,b), least(a,b) );` Oracle can do that too. And, SQL Server can also do it with computed columns.

Comment: @EvanCarroll - MySQL and MariaDB have recently (and independently) added virtual (persistent and not) columns that can be indexed.  Not the same syntax you showed, but same functionality (I think).

Answer (score 1):

## Storage (US Zip Codes)

> The system they have now, utilizes one table for 3 digit to 3 digit system for default properties, and then if exceptions to the 3to3 are needed, there's another table that does the 5 digit to 5 digit.

Just store the zip codes as a `unsigned mediumint`.

- A `mediumint` 3 bytes.
- `char(3)` is three bytes.
- With `mediumint` you can store 0 to 16777215 so you're getting the other two bytes FOR FREE, and you don't have to muck with such sillyness.
- With `mediumint` you can index both your char(3) and char(5) with one index, saving space.
- You can get the results with one index scan, saving time.

Then it you must find all zip codes by the left 3 digits, it just becomes a SELECT condition.

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl
WHERE zip BETWEEN 3_digits * 100 AND (3_digits+1) * 100 - 1;
```

Assuming your 3_digits was 123 that would resolve to

```
WHERE zip BETWEEN 12300 AND 12399;
```

You could even order by,

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl
WHERE zip BETWEEN 3_digits * 100 AND (3_digits+1) * 100 - 1
ORDER BY zip = 5_digits DESC;
```

To find the 5 digits matches first.

## US Zip Codes/Geographical

You say

> I'm working on a project that requires me to allow users to store/edit properties of what they call "path". A path can be any Zip Code to any other Zip Code.

And then

> No. It's not distance. It's various properties of the relationship between those two zips going in that particular direction. Example: Going from Zip1 to Zip2 means you specify AccountA. Zip2 to Zip1 might be AccountB. – SysChaos 30 mins ago

**Zip codes aren't contiguous**: I live in 77345: Google 77345; Google 77344. They're 3 hours away. It doesn't make much sense to *business logic* to make a directional path relay on zip codes which lack cordinality: there can be no such thing as a *path* between two unconnected random zip codes. Take natural numbers, randomize them, and make sense of the path between 3 and 7. **But it's even worse** zip codes, as features, are not regions but points from USPS. Half of the industry use of "zip codes" refer to the Census ZCTA shapefiles which are [only rough approximations of largely arbitrary data points from an internal USPS system](https://github.com/iandees/wtf-zipcodes).

## Business Logic

> The word "path" is just a term. It has no bearing on distances. Let's do Team to Team relationships instead. Maybe I need to store the person who sends emails from T1 to T2. Distance has no impact on that relationship. All we need to know, is that this company has a specific need to specify that a person handles the emails from T1 to T2 and a different person might handle the T2 to A1 emails. That's the situation here, but with zip codes. It's not a geography problem. Imagine 43000 teams that you need to store that level of detail for.

You say you have a 2 billions points and 43,000 teams, we have no idea how you're using Zip Codes to divvy up a workload, however it's unlikely that arbitrary zip codes are an *ideal* solution.

## Summary

So you *can* store the US Zip codes as a single `mediumint` and do what you want, and you'll be better for it and getting rid of the zip3 system you currently have. You'll still have store the Canadian Zip codes in a separate column -- they're not US zip codes so they shouldn't be in the same column anyway, as they have nothing to do with the USPS.

Or, even better, geocode the real address to WGS84 coordinates and use [`ST_Distance`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/st_distance/) or the like, removing zip codes entirely as they have no bearing on geography and can't meaningfully be used in any business logic.

Comment: You probably want `ST_Spherical_Distance` instead.  And that does not account for diff distances depending on direction.

Comment: Distance is not something I store. This is simply properties of a zip to zip relationship.

Comment: @SysChaos I answered that pretty explictly, but *if* you have the address you should instead store the GPS coordinates (GIS geography points) which you can use to calculate the actual distance, rather than inferring distance from the zip code (which is presumably what you're doing with the 3 digits, but that's a *really* bad method.)

Comment: No. It's not distance. It's various properties of the relationship between those two zips going in that particular direction. Example: Going from Zip1 to Zip2 means you specify AccountA. Zip2 to Zip1 might be AccountB.

Comment: @SysChaos I'm not exactly sure of how you're doing business logic here because I don't understand what is means to define *directionaity* in a system that has no concept of *ordinality.* Zip codes are scattered. There is no rhyme or reason to them. It's based on USPS courier system. I'm very much the person to ask these questions to, but something doesn't smell right on that business logic. Unless you simply don't care that it's arbitrary. Either way, even with bad business logic you're certainly storing it wrong. ;)

Comment: @EvanCarroll forgive my rookieness... are you suggesting that I store all of the 5 digit to 5 digit zip combinations (2 billion rows), but then set two indexes on the table to assist with faster lookups and reducing space?

Comment: No, I'm suggesting you store only the 5 digit zip codes as `mediumint` and drop your "3 digit system" entirely using only 5 digit zip codes. You can get the leading three digits of the zip code by dividing `5 digit zip code/100` which I assume will work for your workload, but by doing that you *almost certainly* have other problems in your business logic because there is no need to ever use the leading three digits of a zip code.

Comment: @EvanCarroll Right. That's the original request. Get rid of 3to3. But the 5to5 will leave me with 2 billion rows. I'm not AGAINST that if it fits. Which is why I questioned if there's a better way.

Comment: 2 billion rows on an index is nothing. It'll work and be faster. If not you can look at clustering. If it's not too late to change databases, I would use PostgreSQL. All of these projects eventually take you to GIS. At best, that puts you on the yellow brick road to ESRI, at worst that's a dead end in MySQL.

Comment: Oh wait. Can't do an INT. Have to store Canadian as well.

Comment: @EvanCarroll This is industry standard. It may not make sense to you, but that really doesn't change the goal. I 100% must store properties of a Zip/Zip relationship. And depending upon which zip is first, may change the properties. I may need to store 2 billion rows... and that's fine. I'd chat with you about it, but I don't have enough rep yet. I posted my idea to cut the rowcount down and Rick James went off that as well. So maybe that's a better idea.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting.  Since the distance from A to B can be different from B to A, I think I'd forgo trying to reduce the number of records in favor of keeping your table thin and eliminate column juggling in your query.  Keep all zip code mappings as ZipFrom, ZipTo, and Distance.  This way you won't need any functions in your join to determine which zip column to map to and which distance column to select, which should help with index seek performance.  Then maybe partition the table by the first two digits of the zip code, to cut down on the records searched when querying?